# Android - artifacts when saving a bitmap to a file

Tags: android, graphics

I have a view whose content I wish to save as an image in the gallery. I'm using the following code:

```
   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), view.getDrawingCache(), filename, "desc");
```

When I open the image in the gallery, I see that there are a lot of artifacts around the text areas in the image.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried both JPEG and PNG by compressing the bitmap to a file, and adding the file. In all cases, those artifacts exist.

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem. The Gallery version is the low res Jpeg. My original photo is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Instead of **getContentResolver()**
use **this.getContentResolver()**

Where this is the context of your activity.